# Designing a responsive web application that supposrts ie6

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer, responsive-design

I am building a responsive web application for one of my client. the requirement of the client is that he wants the app to be also supported by internet explorer 6 and successors along with all other latest browsers. how do I start and what should I use for the responsiveness of the web app ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Media queries aren't supported in IE6 through to IE8](http://caniuse.com/#feat=css-mediaqueries). So forget using native media queries, Bootstrap or Foundation.

This polyfill, called Respond.js, may help you - https://github.com/scottjehl/Respond.

Respond.js is a fast & lightweight polyfill for min/max-width CSS3 Media Queries (for IE 6-8, and more)

[Here's a demo example](http://scottjehl.github.io/Respond/test/test.html).

Comment: So in that case i will have to write seperate css files for different browser support? @nashcheez

Comment: this would be time consuming and doesn't make sense when you have frameworks like bootstrap.

Comment: No, you have to write media queries with `max-width` and `min-width` that will be supported in IE 6 with Respond.js. And the same media queries can be used across all other browsers.

Comment: Also, IE 6 came in 2001, Bootstrap launched in 2011 - 10 years apart. Obviously you can write your code in Bootstrap and expect it to be supported by IE 6. You have to use some other framework and/or write some extra code if you do want to support Internet Explorer 6 (God bless you!)